# 500я ошибка при загруке файла в Wordpress из строннего приложения

Tags: wordpress

Есть клиент написаный на js. На клиенте есть место загрузки фотографии. Клиент отправляет файл, на REST-API wordpress. В глобальной $_FILES он появляется, но когда хочу записать его в Uploads при запросе возврвщает ошибку 500 и fatal error

```
function image_test(WP_REST_Request $request){
$data = $request->get_body();
$overrides = ['test' => false];
$result = wp_handle_upload(
    $_FILES['test'],
    $overrides
);
return "return"}
```

Comment: Посмотрите ошибку в логе. Конечно это может не иметь отношения к 500 ошибке, но в `$overrides` можно перезаписать только: `upload_error_handler`, `unique_filename_callback`, `test_form`, `test_size`, `test_upload`, `test_type`, `mime`. Просто параметра `test` там нет. Ну и после `return "return"` должна быть точка с запятой.

Comment: Я уже разобрался, причина в том, что когда отправляется запрос на этот эндпоинт пользователь проходит как гость, а для использования wp_handle_upload(), нужно иметь права администратора

Comment: Админ не нужен, нужен автор и выше. А точнее [роль](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/) с возможностью upload_files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что для таких действий нужны права. Если работать с клиент-серверной архитектурой, нужно найти решение для авторизации клиента. В моём случае это решилось установкой плагина JWT Authentication for WP-API. Просто в запросе в хедерах необходимо передавать авторизационный хедер.

Comment: «авториционный»?

Comment: headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
 },

Comment: так «авториционный» или «авторизационный»? // чтобы исправить текст ответа, нажмите, пожалуйста, [edit]

Comment: спасибо, за бтительность